# how do I write Intellij plugin to display python class methods return value from static analysis (for very simple expressions)?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to write Intellij plugin that can display values returned by class `def()` in python. I would like those values to be evaluated as much as possible and done by static analysis. I need this to work only for very simple expressions in one particular use case.

We have class definitions in our python code base that consist of a lot of **very** simple `def()`s.
All the **defs** are just one return statement returning very simple expression.
All of the code follows the same pattern and uses very few python operator.

the code is long and really hard to follow.
After few jumps "to definition" within this class I can't remember where I am anymore.

I am hoping that some intellij plugin can lessen the pain.

So for example. this is short and very simplified code fragment.  hopefully it will be enough to demonstrate the problem.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
    def a(self):
        return self.param + 1
    def b(self):
        return self.a + otherfunc()
    def c(self):
        return self.b + 3
```

I would like the plugin to display the following:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
    def a(self): # = param + 1
        return self.param + 1
    def b(self): # = param + 1 + otherfunc()
        return self.a + otherfunc()
    def c(self): # = param + 1 + otherfunc() + 3
        return self.b + 3
```

This is just an illustration, real code makes more sense. but the expressions themselves are that simple.

Comments represent plugin output. I would like those values to be always visible as code hints, tooltips or whatever. and be updated as I type.

I don't want to evaluate the *def*s, because some of the values are not available before runtime. I want to get the expression itself from AST.

Obviously this is impossible to do in the general case. But I have a very specific use case in our code base
where very small python subset is used. And all the code follows the same pattern.

I already have a script that does this in python with `ast` module. I wonder if there is a way to do the same on the fly in Intellij.

Is there some way to achieve this? or something similar?
Is there a plugin that does something like that?

I doubt that there is. at least not exactly. So I want to try to implement it myself.  (the use case is common and very annoying).
I skimmed through some of Intellij Platform Plugin SDK documentation. it's still not clear to me where to begin.

So what would be the easiest way to implement it from scratch or using another plugin as an example?

Is there an opensource plugin that does something similar that I can look at to figure out how to implement this myself?

My best guess is that I would need to implement:

- create a call back that will be called every time `def()` is changed.  (by implementing various *extensions*, no? which one?)
- find this **def** in the file.
- walk expression with PSI to extract the expression
- create some GUI element to represent the *def* expression. (what are my options? is there some predefined elements that I can use?
  ideally I would assign value to some existing GUI element)
- assign value to the GUI element

but I don't know how to begin implementing any of the above. (I can probably figure out PSI part)

I searched for existing plugins, but couldn't find anything even remotely close. I skimmed the documentation, I did the tutorial, but I couldn't figure out which of the many extensions I need to use.

I considered using the debugger for that, but I don't see how debugger can help me here.

Any help (plugins, tutorials, extensions, plugins as an example, or details for implementation) would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to find is some [extension point](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-extension-points.html) that will change the text user sees. I suggest you to look at the [annotator](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-178c8565735689ec2663b7ed21a7e817a1e368cf/platform/analysis-api/src/com/intellij/lang/annotation/Annotator.java) class but maybe this is not the best extension point for you and you will need to find more suitable one (this is the most difficult part of creating plugins for JetBrain's IDEs). Full list of all available extension points you can find [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/extension-point-list.html).

After you find right extension point you need to implement it and change `plugin.xml` to let IDE know that some changes were made.

Some useful links:

- [Example plugins from developers](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-code-samples)
- [Official documentation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/basics.html)
- [Quick course from JetBrain's developer (in Russian)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoTrgA2zOJI)